# Get the best results from my real time application

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, jquery-plugins

### **Best practices for realtime application**

Hello, Im looking to create an efficient way to create a live chat.

The technologies I can use right now:

1. PHP
2. MySql
3. jQuery / Ajax
4. Html5
5. CSS

I have made a little research and I found something very Interesting called [long polling](https://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery)

From the url the solution I found was to do the next

```
(function poll() {
   setTimeout(function() {
       $.ajax({ url: "server", success: function(data) {
            sales.setValue(data.value);
       }, dataType: "json", complete: poll });
    }, 30000);
})();
```

Which is very effective compared to `setInterval` and in my opinion that would be the best way to do it given the current technology im using, as im not a very experienced guy I wanted to ask you If you could help me create a more efficient piece of code if it's possible.

Would be better to learn something like node js
And also would that be a good idea to create a real time application like a chat for an application that could get for example 1,000,000 members?
I think the servers could crash and that scares me, or if a user is chatting with 20 users at the same time what could be caused?

PS:
I looking to use AWS as it seems that I would get good results for my users besides the technique or technology I use.

Comment: Investigate websockets or webRTC also. Lots of different approaches available for creating chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll recommend learning socket.io

Using ajax long polling to create a web chat will work - but it is not the best and effective way to do it.

> Writing a chat application with popular web applications stacks like
>   LAMP (PHP) has traditionally been very hard. It involves polling the
>   server for changes, keeping track of timestamps, and it’s a lot slower
>   than it should be.
>
> Sockets have traditionally been the solution around which most
>   realtime chat systems are architected, providing a bi-directional
>   communication channel between a client and a server.
>
> This means that the server can push messages to clients. Whenever you
>   write a chat message, the idea is that the server will get it and push
>   it to all other connected clients.

https://socket.io